# Mocking an action payload with redux-saga-test-plan

Tags: redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

Given a saga that operates over the action payload, where `action` has been passed in by `takeLatest` e.g.

```
export function* mySaga(action) {
  try {
    yield all(action.payload.items.map(p => call(doSomething, p)));
    }
    yield put(actionSuccess());
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actionFailed(error));
  }
}

export function* watchMySaga() {
  yield takeLatest(AN_ACTION, mySaga);
}
```

how do I mock `action` in my `redux-saga-test-plan` test for `mySaga`? As `action.payload` is `undefined`, my test currently throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears, you simply pass a mock action object as the second argument to `expectSaga`, e.g.

```
return expectSaga(mySaga, action)
    .provide([[...]])
    .put(actionSuccess())
    .run();
```